# Done with a guess-the-word riddle!

Tags: riddle

The end of every process.
Also a language spoken.
The appearance you bless.
If something's it, they may be broken.

Please kindly improve I currently can't think of words that rhyme ackkkkk

Comment: is the answer related to religions (amin)?

Comment: unfortunately, no. but you're still welcome to put that as an answer! Remember to explain why! @Q̞ī̯X̶͇͇͇͇͇͇͇͇͇͇͇͇͇̯̯̳̳͈͈͈͆͆

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Finish

The end of every process.

> The finish can mean the end of a task or process.

Also a language spoken.

> Finish sounds like Finnish (from Finland)

The appearance you bless.

> The finish can also be used to describe the surface appearance of a manufactured material or object.

If something's it, they may be broken.

> If something is finished, it may be broken.

Also, as pointed out by the OP, the title is related

> Done is synonymous with finished

Comment: Ye good job! The riddles I make are probably too easy...

Comment: And the title is kinda related (done --> finish)